# stat structure unitialized local variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl, stat

So basically, after compiling my program in debug mode I get one error (surprisingly) -- just in the curl component.

I am trying to transfer a file over the internet so I declare

```
curl_off_t size;
struct stat file;
size = (curl_off_t)file.st_size;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)size);
```

but when I compile my project I get the error code in the log like so:

`1 error C4700: uninitialized local varabile 'file' used`

I included the curl libraries and even stat.h 
Why is this error occuring?

Comment: I think it must be because you activated "warning as error" because I don't see how `un-initialized variable used` should be a compile time error. You usually get a CRT assert in debug mode whenever it can catch this kind of things.

Comment: also regarding the actual error message, how is st_sized supposed to get filled up with something relevant ? because its what it says. you just declare a stack variable, which content will be garbage, and you immediatly cast it, use the content to put in a function that will just be fed garbage.

Comment: I specified `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in the preprocessor definition, but thats only since the compiler cried out with atleast 50 different kinds of errors (debug compilation), and recommended I put that in.

Comment: `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` simply removes warning related to string functions like `strncpy`.